# Get a feed on Facebook Page with Graph API ordered by created time or updated time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When user comments or reply to comments to a older post , in graph api how to get those feeds sorted by time.

Answer (score 0):

Raised Bug to Facebook and here is the response

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/469327419867332